# Custom order in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have an oracle query in which and i want the result to be in custom order 'SENIOR DIRECTOR', 'DIRECTOR', 'MANAGER', 'EMPLOYEE' which is from the field GRADE_DESCRIPTON. I am using the below query.

However I am not getting the desired result 
The order of the result im getting is  'SENIOR DIRECTOR','MANAGER', DIRECTOR,'EMPLOYEE'

```
SELECT DISTINCT GRADE_DESCRIPTION
      , HIRING_FORECATS.*  
FROM GRADE_MASTER left join     HIRING_FORECATS 
   ON (HIRING_FORECATS.GRADE = GRADE_MASTER.GRADE_DESCRIPTION 
        and HIRING_FORECATS.LOCATION = 'HO' )   
 order by decode    
 (GRADE_MASTER.GRADE_DESCRIPTION, 'SENIOR DIRECTOR', 'DIRECTOR', 'MANAGER', 'EMPLOYEE')
```

Any Suggestions??

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
ORDER BY DECODE(
         GRADE_MASTER.GRADE_DESCRIPTION,
         'SENIOR DIRECTOR', 1,
         'DIRECTOR', 2,
         'MANAGER', 3,
         'EMPLOYEE', 4,
         5)
```

Answer (score 10):

The point about `decode()` is that for each pair of values it substitutes teh second value for the first.  So your posted query sorts 'SENIOR DIRECTOR' as 'DIRECTOR', 'MANAGER' as 'EMPLOYEE'  and everybody else randomly after that.

So what you need to do is assign a sort order to each value.  The most future-proof way of handling this would be to assign a SORT_ORDER column to the GRADE_DESCRIPTION table, but that is not always practical.  So if you only have one or two reports which need to be sorted in this way (seems likely) then you can just continue with the hard-coded descriptions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GRADE_DESCRIPTION
      , HIRING_FORECATS.*  
FROM GRADE_MASTER left join     HIRING_FORECATS 
   ON (HIRING_FORECATS.GRADE = GRADE_MASTER.GRADE_DESCRIPTION 
        and HIRING_FORECATS.LOCATION = 'HO' )   
 order by decode    
 (GRADE_MASTER.GRADE_DESCRIPTION
    , 'SENIOR DIRECTOR', 10
      , 'DIRECTOR', 20
      , 'MANAGER', 30
      , 'EMPLOYEE', 40
      , 100)
```

It is a good idea to include a default value, just in case.  I also like to leave large gaps in the sort numbers, to make it easier to slot in a new value.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a SQL CASE instead of a PL/SQL DECODE:

```
order by CASE WHEN GRADE_MASTER.GRADE_DESCRIPTION = 'SENIOR DIRECTOR' THEN 1
          WHEN GRADE_MASTER.GRADE_DESCRIPTION = 'DIRECTOR' THEN 2
          WHEN GRADE_MASTER.GRADE_DESCRIPTION = 'MANAGER' THEN 3
          WHEN GRADE_MASTER.GRADE_DESCRIPTION = 'EMPLOYEE' THEN 4
          ELSE 5
      END
```

This will keep the parser from switching between SQL and PL/SQL modes.

Comment: Fnord.  'decode()' is a SQL function and always has been.  In fact, unlike `case()` it cannot be used in PL/SQL (except as part of an embedded SQL statement).

Answer (score 2):

You could add a new column to `GRADE_MASTER` to represent the ordering or levels. This would allow you to change the order by clause to:

```
ORDER BY GRADE_MASTER.GRADE_ORDER
```

And has the advantage of only requiring changes to the `GRADE_MASTER` table when a new grade is introduced.